# Unhandled JS Exception: Unexpected token '<' no stack

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, react-native, bundle

I started facing an issue with running my react native application in iOS device

```
   Unhandled JS Exception: Unexpected Token '<' no stack
```

This started happening after i generated the main.jsbundle in react native application using the below curl command

```
   curl http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle -o main.jsbundle
```

and added this file in xcode project. This seems to like an issue with parsing of the main.jsbundle file which i added in react-native.

Prior to the above process i tried running the application with localhost:8081 for finding the jsbundle but doesn't help me for ios devices. Code in my develop branch is working fine, but same develop code in my feature branch doesn't work with main.jsbundle.

Did anyone faced similar issue with running react native code in iOS devices.

Answer (score 0):

The response you're getting is most likely in HTML format, which starts with a `<`. When you try to parse this response (presumably with `res.json()`) an exception is thrown, because a json string cannot start with a `<`

Try debugging your program and check exactly what the response you're getting is